# Java Extracting Characters and Integers from String

Tags: java, string, split, integer, extract

I have this method that receives a string that contains an integer at the end, i've tried to extract the characters and the integer this way:

```
public void findCardPosition(String cardLocation,ImageView cardImage){
        String cardName = null;
        String cardType = cardLocation.replaceAll("[^a-z]","");
        String cardPosition = cardLocation.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
        int position = Integer.parseInt(cardPosition)-1;
        if(cardType=="territory"){
            cardName=GameBoard.getTerritoryTower().placeTowerTerritories().get(position).getName();
        }

        if(cardLocation=="territory1"){
            cardName=GameBoard.getTerritoryTower().placeTowerTerritories().get(position).getName();
        }
        if(cardName!=null){
            this.findCardImage(cardName,cardImage);
        }
    }
```

In theory both IF should work but the first one doesn't which means that when i apply `String cardType = cardLocation.replaceAll("[^a-z]","");` to the string `"territory1"` it doesn't return the string `"territory".` The string `cardPosition`works, so i don't understand why the string`cardType`doesn't.

Comment: cardType=="territory"

Comment: never ever in java

Comment: Use `equals()` or `contains()` instead to compare strings in Java. Also, a java String is immutable. What is returned by `String.replaceAll()` is a copy.